# Workflow Triggering - After every list update

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, workflow

I have two workflows on a list that track the status of issues entered by users.

The first Workflow "Completed" does the following:

1. Checks if a status indicator has been set to closed
2. Emails the issue creator with details on the closure

My second workflow tracks issues that have been reopened after closure.

1. Checks if a indicator called Reopen? has been set to Yes
2. If yes the status indicator is changed from "Closed" to "Under Review"
3. The person who closed the issue is emailed informing them that the issue has been reopened

This issue is that I'm receiving two closure emails, when the item is marked as closed (expected) and when the item is reopened (unexpected). Is there a way I can limit the closure emails so the workflows function as I expected?

I'm assuming that if someone changed another field in the list, Line of Business for example the closure email would re trigger if the status is closed?

Answer (score 1):

I got the issue.

Solution - Create only one workflow which will contain all conditions and actions.

Issue - Your second workflows is running twice, once when someone changes the item and then when the workflow first workflow get completed, this triggers second workflow to run again.

You can verify this issue form item level workflow history.

Answer (score 0):

If the order of the sequence is going to run in the same order every time you can use a new item workflow and use a "Wait for field change in current item" action (SPD 2013).  This way the workflow only does the action one time for each condition.

Another option, which I use in SPD 2007, is to create a hidden field that you set when an action is performed and then check against that hidden field each time the workflow runs.  You can use this method in change item workflows to prevent any updates from firing the action beyond the initial trigger.  If you look at the screenshot in the post I left below you can see an example of this.

[Workflow when specific field changes in a List](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/186976/workflow-when-specific-field-changes-in-a-list/186993#186993)